We've cleared the backlog of "In need of moderator intervention" flags
After the end of the 2023 moderators and curators strike, the flag queue of "In need of moderator intervention" flags — a.k.a. custom flags, mod flags, etc. was quite literally over 9000! flags long.
The vast majority of those flags were backlogged AI flags. It took us a long time to clear that backlog — and we understand this caused a great deal of frustration to many people who had their flags pending for a long time. We tried to search for and prioritize non-AI flags lost in the haystack but that strategy had its limits too. Anyway, as promised, we got back on top of it.
At the time of writing, the "In need of moderator intervention" queue has only 3 pending flags: the oldest remaining one dated January 2024, one a mere 1 week old and one from yesterday.
This herculean effort wouldn't have been possible without the new great moderators who joined the team last election so a big thanks goes to them. Handling the backlog hasn't been all though. We also kept up with the newer flags that come in every day. Therefore, another big thanks must go to all moderators who helped keep the other flag queues in check while the "In need of moderator intervention" one was being chipped at.
The job isn't done though. There's still a sizeable backlog of plagiarism flags — but it's one good order of magnitude less than the numbers previously mentioned, actually even less — that now will start getting some more attention.
We all hope to be able to moderate this site without any more prolonged disruptions.

Trash tidied up. Image in the public domain (CC0). Source.

Thanks for the cleanup efforts, it can't have been easy cleaning up after the strike.

Thanks for this post. Checks out: I have two remaining pending flags and they are both basically plagiarism. — Please do let us know what we can do to assist mods. It may not be obvious, but as flaggers we greatly value our "personal" relationship with mods and want to categorize things in the way that makes most sense to them. This is a partnership and as flaggers we are very aware that we're taking up the time and attention of a busy human being.

@matt I second your idea. I am proposing to include some marker words, says "verbatim", in the plagiarism flag message. These marker words should be used only if the plagiarist simply copy and paste from another source. The words may help to tell mods it is a low-hanging fruit and may speed up the review process

Bah. You only accomplished this by declining all 8999 of my NAA flags!

It's fortunate this isn't a maths site or that would be more than 8E31681 items in the queue(!)

Awesome job, thank you all. As for "We all hope to be able to moderate this site without any more prolonged disruptions": I'm sure the company still has a few tricks up its sleeve.

As a young developer and someone slowly taking part in this whole community, I am awed by the moderator team's efforts and inspired to learn more, so I too can help in the future.

Not sure which Greek myth to invoke here, but this was either a Herculean or Sisyphean task, or both! Well done.

@matt I appreciate the thought, however there isn't much that regular users can do. If we consider flags being divided in three main classes — 1. red flags (spam and R/A), 2. NAA/VLQ, and 3. other — it's enough to get the class right to help us prioritize issues. The company could implement one more flag type for AI content. If those went into their own bucket, all other non-AI flags wouldn't be drowned out. But as long as the flag queue doesn't completely get out of hand, that isn't much of an issue either.

@Starship in the months before the strike all flag queues were under control

Hardware flashback!

Congratulations! Call me back when the flag queue is 0.

I'm a bit late, but wanted to note the mod team effort here. Flag totals from the last quarter shown below. The flag queue, currently, is basically empty. Serious credit is due blackgreen and Dalija Prasnikar in particular for working the custom queue so diligently. It's a job that deserves some public praise.


Nice job! The new ones are the ones that usually get the worst of the clean up piles. :D

@BhargavRao queue is virtually zero, time to ask for reinstatement, eh!?
